# Fix nginx configuration to allow iframes

Tags: nginx, iframe, digital-ocean, x-frame-options

I contact you because I have tried during several days to add my droplet from digital ocean in an iframe on my website.
It keeps on telling me that it doesn't work because my X-Frame-Options is set at sameorigin, which I checked in the header, is true.
I tried several things to make it work.
First I tried to see if I could change the X-Frame-Options in my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file. So I added:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
```

I tried in the html bit as well as server bit or location part but it never worked and when looking at the header response I always had same origin and not deny (I know I shouldn't put deny to allow iframes but this was to check whether I was acting at the right place).
I've also tried to add some CSP as follows:

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors 'self' mysite.com;
```

but it's not appearing in my header either... Nothing seems to change my header. What should I do? I tried to restart my droplet and use grep to check whether there were other places with X-Frame-Options but it is not the case. Please help me as it's driving me nuts.

Here is my Nginx config file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;
        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

and here is my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;


        location / {
               
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
        server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name sub.domain.com;

        root /var/www/sub.domain.com;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right. I found out that my server was run with traefik and not nginx directly and so I had to set up the config in the traefik.toml file.